# No symbol for COMDAT section

Tags: linker, clang, llvm, symbols, llvm-ir

Been working on my own language for some time now and I've been implementing implicit and explicit casts. Went back to check what happens when invoking them. Everything went well, until I tried to invoke a cast from a double. Passing doubles to functions for some reason results in clang giving me an error when linking the obj file to the cpp file that invokes it, namely:"clang.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1143 (use -v to see invocation)program.obj : fatal error LNK1143: invalid or corrupt file: no symbol for COMDAT section 0x5"

I've then noticed this also happens with floats, but does not occur with integers and the likes. I've written a short function (takes a double by value and returns it) to check whether the problem was related to parameters of types float/double. The error only occurs when invoking the function, when defining the function but not invoking it, everything functioned properly. I've also tried to simply store a double literal in memory (alloca) and that worked as well, so the problem has to be with actually passing the argument to the function.

[image]

Simple LLVM IR for a function that takes a double by value and returns it, then being invoked from main (main is names _mainCRTStartup as to not confuse it with the symbol for the main function from the cpp file that then invokes it (extern "C"))

Thanks for any help in advance! :D